# What characters are legal for Haxe method/function names?

Tags: methods, haxe

I'm creating a JSON-RPC library and I need to know what characters are allowed as Haxe method names.  I know that I must be cautious of allowed method names in the target languages as well, but I'm trying to start with Haxe : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpha or underscore for the first symbol and alpanumeric or underscore for the next symbols.

```
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

is the regexp for haxe method name.

Comment: Link to source would be nice : )

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/lexer.mll#L221